# What is the CSS syntax for a named span class nested in a div?

Tags: html, css

In the following, how do I reference the "name" class?

```
<div class="resultDetails">
<span class="name">Name</span>
<span class="address">Address</span>
</div>
```

Comment: As you can see from your available responses, you really need to figure out if there are any limiting factors here. Do you only need `name` where it comes on a `span`? only within `resultDetails`? only directly after `div` s?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
div span.name { ... }
```

`div` .. tells the element type

a space then `span` .. tells to look at span elements in sub levels

`.name` .. tells to look at those elements with css class named `name`

Answer (score 5):

```
div.resultDetails > span.name { ... }
```

Should work.

Comment: I would say that you shouldn't have `div` there unless you want these styles to only apply to a div tag.... sticking with CSS selectors without tags reduces the file size of stylesheets, so it's a good practice.

Comment: @webnet: OP was specific about getting _that_ span tag so I want the explicit route. I do tend to agree with you though.

Comment: I think this is offtopic. Maybe he needs an general aproch maybe he wants to set a style for this specific combination of a div and span.

Answer (score 5):

simply

```
<style>
.name
{

}
</style>
```

All you need is the name of the class itself,  unless other factors
otherwise you can use several types of selectors

```
div span.name // selects all spans with class "name" in any div
div > span.name // this one selects only the spans that are direct children of a div
div.resultDetails span.name //select only spans with class "name" in only divs with class="result Details
.resultDetails .name // selects any element with class "name" in any element with class "resultDetails"
```

There are more ways of selecting but you get the point.

Answer (score 2):

div.resultDetails > span.name works in most browsers.

However, it doesn't work in IE6. If that's an issue, just using:
div.resultDetails span.name {} should target the span correctly (provided you dont have any nested span.name elements inside the div that you don't intend to target).